# Is there a way to stylize specific data retrieved from MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am pulling data from my mySQL database and outputting it onto my page fine, however, I want to style specific data on the page using Bootstrap. I've tried to write functions to pull the data separately, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

This is for a simple CRUD database using PHP and mySQL, styled with Bootstrap 4 and JQuery. I've tried to write a function within the page in place of `$row[status]`, but I think I'm missing a step.

The table should output either `"EXP"` or `"PAID"` under `$row["status"]`.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
        <h2>Results</h2>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["status"]); ?></td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="update-single.php?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

If the `$row["status"]` from the table `= "EXP"` I want to wrap it with a span HTML
example: `<span class="badge badge-danger"> </span>` to wrap, else if it's `"PAID"` `<span class="badge badge-success"> </span>` gets wrapped around `"PAID"`

Comment: cant you just do an if\else and echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `<td><?php echo escape($row["status"]); ?></td>` with:

```
<td>
<?php
    if($row["status"]=='EXP'){//assumes exp and paid are only option otherwise use an elseif
       echo '<span class="badge badge-danger">';
    }else{
       echo '<span class="badge badge-success">';
    }
echo escape($row["status"]).'</span>';
?>
</td>
```

Comment: This solution was so simple. Thank you so much, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

I've wrapped your span as required and made it a bit more readable with the ":" notation instead of curly brackets

```php
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])): ?>
    <?php if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0): ?>
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?></td>
                    <?php if ($row["status"] === "EXP"): ?>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-danger"><?php echo escape($row["status"]); ?></span></td>
                    <?php elseif ($row["status"] === "PAID"): ?>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success"><?php echo escape($row["status"]); ?></span></td>
                    <?php endif: ?>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="update-single.php?id=<?php echo escape($row["id"]); ?>">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If duplicating HTML isn't your thing. You can use a variable in the loop and switch the `badge-{name}` class name to your liking.

Comment: Thank you, will try this out!

Comment: I liked this solution, but it was a little more duplicative. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `status` have only 2 possible values: `EXP` or `PAID`.

You could modify the table cell like this:

```
<td><span class="badge badge-<?php echo $row["status"] == "EXP" ? 'danger' : 'success' ?>"><?php echo escape($row["status"]); ?></span></td>
```